# Respond to multiple Keypress using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am working with jquery and wants to redirect to new page when two or more keywords are pressed. 
Currently I am trying to use "\ + b"(holding down \ and pressing b) for redirection and it does not redirects me. 
And also I was trying to figure out how to prevent redirection second time when only b is pressed.

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 220 && e.keyCode == 66) {
    window.location.replace("signup.php");
  }
});
```

Thank you for your support.
Any additional information is helpful.

Comment: `e.keyCode` is a property, and therefor cannot be equal to 2 values at once. Given that, this if statement will never be true. I would take a look at the [KeyboardEvent.GetModifierState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/getModifierState) method.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable, and toggle between `true` or `false` using the [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) and [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) events

You can then use this variable inside your current `if` statement

```js
let backslashPressed = false;

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 220) {
    backslashPressed = true;
  }
});

$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 220) {
    backslashPressed = false;
  }
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (backslashPressed && e.keyCode == 66) {
    console.log('signup.php');
    // window.location.replace("signup.php");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! Also, if this answer has helped you, could you mark it as accepted - This will reward both you and I with some reputation, and will mark your question as solved. [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)